# App Store showing wrong screenshots for wrong phone

Tags: ios, screenshot, app-store-connect

On iTunesConnect, I submitted scaled app screenshots for the iPhone 6, iPhone 5, and the iPhone 4s. However, when I view the app on the App Store, I only see the 4s screenshots regardless of what device I am using (I have physical access to all three devices). These screenshots are not simply in-app screenshots, they have been formatted to show the app running on the physical device itself so the difference is notable. I have experienced this problem on both of my app submissions, is there anyway this can be remedied?

Comment: Yes, iTunesConnect will not let you submit screenshots which don't meet their exact dimension requirements. I mean that the screenshot is not just a screenshot taken from the app, the entire screenshot consists of a device running the app, so it's like in third person. This way, if someone on iPhone 6 looks at the app on the app store, they will see pictures of an iPhone 6 running the app.

Comment: My bad... I can't help you with this... I've submitted my apps multiple times with the correct screenshots being displayed on different devices. Perhaps uploading your itunes connect settings might help others to help you out..

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will do this as soon as I can. In the meantime, it would help me if you upvoted my question, to garner more attention if possible!

Comment: Hi, what you comment is not possible, unless there is a lag between what the servers show because they have not yet updated all the info. Apple's servers tend to show a mix of information from the apps at the moment a new version is being released. Could you provide a link to see this strange case, in the case your app submissions were some time ago (not one or two days)?

Comment: I just submitted an update, which got approved a few hours ago. However, I have been experiencing this problem even with my last version. Here is the link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-grade/id921238499?mt=8

Comment: You have done a very strange thing. You have submitted strangely scaled images. In fact, you are showing an iPhone 5 (see rounded button) but which has been deformed. Can you supply a link to the original image?

Comment: Yes the images came from an app designed to make iPhone screenshots, I then scaled the images to meet the dimension requirements. This is not what is bothering me however. If I were to view my app on the app store on my iPhone 6, I will still see the iPhone 5 screenshots. That is my problem. Unfortunately, I do not have the original images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you uploaded the correct image size for each dimensions respectively? Not sure what do you mean by scaled app screenshots. I've uploaded different set of images for 4.7inch, 5.5inch, 4inch, 3.5inch,iPad without any issues. For your case you need to submit for 4.7inch, 4 inch and 3.5 inch. Please refer to this guide for the correct image dimension:

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Long answer:

**3.5-Inch Retina Display Screenshots (required)**
Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots. Screenshot requirements are:
72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
Any of the following sizes:
640 x 920 pixels for hi-res portrait (without status bar) minimum
640 x 960 pixels for hi-res portrait (full screen) maximum
960 x 600 pixels for hi-res landscape (without status bar) minimum
960 x 640 pixels for hi-res landscape (full screen) maximum

4-Inch Retina Display Screenshots (Required)
Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots. Screenshot requirements are:
72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
Any of the following sizes:
640 x 1096 pixels for portrait (without status bar) minimum
640 x 1136 pixels for portrait (full screen) maximum
1136 x 600 pixels for landscape (without status bar) minimum
1136 x 640 pixels for landscape (full screen) minimum

4.7-inch Retina screenshot
Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots. Screenshot requirements are:
72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait
1334 x 750 pixels for hi-res landscape